# Is there a way to auto select the elements to export when exporting a jar in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, configuration

I'm trying to find a way to export a jar in vscode without having to select what to include everytime and I just can't seem to find any info for it on the internet. Is there a way to do that or am I just not able to? [Here's a screenshot of what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqIsv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a look at [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/wiki/Export-Your-Project-to-a-Jar)?

> You will see the wizard choosing the elements of the output jar. You
> will see a list including output folders and the dependency artifacts
> of the workspace
>
> The runtime elements are chosen by default while the test ones are
> not. You can choose the elements you need and click OK.
>
> note: If only one element is found in your workspace, this step will
> be skipped and the element will be included in the export jar
> automatically. nm